# How i know if a Sound object is playing?

Tags: actionscript-3

In AS3 i've created a code that load a sound and execute it in streaming.

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
mySound.load(new URLRequest("surrender.mp3"));
myChannel = mySound.play();
```

Considering that the mp3 file is placed on the server, i need to trace if it's already begun or still receiving initial data from the server. Once it's effectively started i've to call a function that initialize some things.

the problem is, how i can trace if a sound or channel object "is playing" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this by listening for the different Events the Sound object dispatches as well as its properties like Sound.isBuffering

Refer to the [Sound manpage](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html)

Answer (score 0):

you could wait for the mp3 to be loaded completely

```
var myChannel:SoundChannel;
var soundFactory:Sound = new Sound();
soundFactory.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
soundFactory.load(request);

// ...

private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    trace("completeHandler: " + event);
    myChannel = soundFactory.play();
}
```

or you can use a `Timer` and check the `myChannel.position` periodically - if it doesn't change the sound stopped playing...